# MySQL auto_increment query sticks at one value, regardless of how many rows are inserted

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table (InnoDB) that when queried shows the SAME auto_increment value both before and after an insert.

First thing I did when I encountered this was to delete out the rows that were there and reset the auto_increment:

```
  alter table rx3d auto_increment = 1;
```

When inserting rows now, it gives the correct auto_increment values: 1, 2, 3 etc
The rows are coming out as expected

However, when I try to query what the next auto_increment value is to be, I get just one number, 24.
Why that number I do not know.

The query used (I believe is correct) is this:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ul'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'rx3d';
```

This queried value for auto_increment doesn't change, after any row insert!?

I'm baffled.

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and MySQL Community Server 8.0.18 (x86_64)

Comment: I would use `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rx3d';` This will show only next AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: @IvanGanchev, No it won't. MySQL 8.0 does not update the information_schema.tables stats, including auto_increment, except once per day. See the answer in the question I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I saw and understood the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks all. It turns out that this (newer) version of MySQL is set to only update auto_increment every 24 hours. So, a quick think and I've come up with a workaround that works. I could have changed the settings so MySQL updated the value moment by moment, but that seemed lamer than my workaround.